# Need PL/SQL stored procedure to convert column into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, plsqldeveloper

I have table as -

```
filename    description                                 value
--------    ------------------------------------------  --------------------
rec_123     PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_month             February 2018
rec_123     rows_PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_description  property write count
rec_123     PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_value_value       1234
rec_123     PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_value_baseType    LONG
```

I want to convert it into -

```
filename  month            value    description                 value_basetype
--------  -------------    -----    -------------------------   --------------       
rec_2134  February 2018    1234     PropertyWriteCount_rows_0   long
```

I could able to write PL/SQL till this point, need help for next steps -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rows_column IS
  CURSOR get_rows IS
    SELECT * FROM table1 where description LIKE 'PropertyWriteCount_rows%';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('table info -');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    filename,
    max(case when description = 'PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_month'            then value end) as month,
    max(case when description = 'rows_PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_description' then value end) as description,
    max(case when description = 'PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_value_value'      then value end) as value,
    max(case when description = 'PropertyWriteCount_rows_0_value_baseType'   then value end) as value_basetype
from table1 
where description like '%PropertyWriteCount_rows%'
group by filename
```

Comment: Thanks, i found 2 issues 
1) this generated single record of filename column (rec_2134) but i have multiple records how we can handle it 
2) my description won't be always 'PropertyWriteCount_rows_0', Can we add like in case ?

Comment: (1) This is not showing in your sample data, so I cannot comment on that (2) Sure, you can change the equality to a `like` condition. For example: `max(case when description like 'PropertyWriteCount_rows_%_month'  then value end) as month`.

Comment: I still want to understand if i have to fetch multiple records of filename then how we can handle ?

Comment: @AkashSarpate - Please edit your question to include more sample data.  If there are to be multiple rows in the output with the same `filename`, how do you know which rows you want to aggregate together?  When you edit your question and include that sample data, please make sure to explain the logic you want to implement for picking which rows to combine in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` clause after rendering `description` column in order to extract the last word after last underscore from that column.

The following query might be used as a *static approach*

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,'[^_]+$') AS title,
          filename, value
     FROM table1 )
  PIVOT
  (
   MAX(value) FOR title IN ('month' AS month, 'value' AS value, 
                            'description' AS description, 'baseType' AS baseType) 
  )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1427d1284575e9f784dc5769e8b9b3c0)</kbd>

but a *dynamic approach* should be preferred rather, through creating a stored function as in the following PL/SQL code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_File_Values RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_col       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||titles||''' AS '||titles , ',' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY titles DESC )
    INTO v_col
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,'[^_]+$') AS titles  
             FROM table1 ); 

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT *
     FROM (
           SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,''[^_]+$'') AS title,
                  filename, value
             FROM table1
          )
    PIVOT
    (
     MAX(value) FOR title IN ( '|| v_col ||' )
    )';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

Then running the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_File_Values;
PRINT rc
```

from **SQL Developer**'s *Command Line*

***or***

```
BEGIN
  :result := Get_File_Values;
END;
```

from *Test window* of **PL/SQL Developer** (*as tagged*)

in order to see the expected result set varying even if the new values for `description` column are inserted or some former values are deleted.